# Parameter pack expansion fails

Tags: visual-studio, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Consider the following simplified C++ code:

```
template <typename ... TEventArgs>
struct Event
{
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
struct Parameter
{
    using Type = T;
    // ...
};

template <typename ... Parameters>
struct Command
{
    Event<typename Parameters::Type...> Invoked;
};

int main()
{
    Command<Parameter<int>, Parameter<float>> c;
}
```

The Visual Studio C++ compiler (November 2013 CTP, Visual Studio 2013 Update 1) produces the following error:
source.cpp(17): error C3546: '...' : there are no parameter packs available to expand

Mingw 4.8.1. on the other hand compiles the code without any problems. Apparently, the Visual Studio compiler has a bug that prevents it from expanding the parameter pack when the expression involves accessing a type of the variadic parameters. Other expansions work, though. For instance, `Event<std::vector<Parameters>...> Invoked;` compiles successfully or you could even successfully access static members to call a variadic function like this in `Command`'s constructor: `SomeVariadicFunc(Parameters::SomeStaticFunc()...);`.

So, the questions are:

1) Which compiler is wrong: Visual Studio or mingw? Although I don't see anything that would prevent the `typename Parameters::Type` parameter pack expansion from working, I'm not 100% sure it's valid C++.

2) Is there a work around? Basically, I would have to perform a projection from a "sequence" of `Parameters` to a "sequence" of `Parameters::Type`. Is that possible? I tried to construct that list using a recursive struct but I could only come up with something like `myStruct<type1, mystruct<type2, mystruct<type3, ...>>>`, which is not what I need.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `typename<typename T> using Type=T;` then `Event< Type<Parameters::Type>... >`, or if your compiler lacks `using` aliases, `template<typename T>struct type{typedef T type;}` and `Event<typename type<typename Parameters::Type>::type>`?  Failing that, `template<typename T> using get_type=typename T::type;` and `Event< get_type<Parameters>... >`?  Basically make a run-around the parser.

Comment: Unfortunately, both suggestions don't work. The last one gives the following errors: _source.cpp(21): error C3546: '...' : there are no parameter packs available to expand_ and _source.cpp(21): error C3203: 'get_type' : unspecialized alias template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'TEventArgs', expected a real type_ Again, compiles fine with mingw 4.8.1. Thanks anyway for these suggestions.

Comment: `template<typename T>struct get_type_2{typedef typename T::Type type;};` then `Event< typename get_type_2<Parameters>::type... >`?  Or `Event< decltype( std::declval<typename get_type_2<Parameters>::type>() )... >` to move the `...` expansion into an expression?  (last one might need a `decay`)  I'm just stabbing at possible flaws in their compiler, thinking what could go wrong...

Comment: Thank you very much - the first suggestion of your second post solved the problem. Compiles perfectly now with both Visual Studio and mingw. I've opened a bug report on connect, linking to your work around. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yakk was able to come up with a workaround for the problem in the comments above. The final version that compiles perfectly with both Visual Studio an mingw is the following:

```
template <typename ... TEventArgs>
struct Event
{
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
struct Parameter
{
    using Type = T;
    // ...
};

template <typename ... Parameters>
struct Command
{
private:
    // Workaround for the Visual Studio bug
    template<typename T> struct ExpandArgs
    {
        typedef typename T::Type Type;
    };

public:
    Event<typename ExpandArgs<Parameters>::Type...> Invoked;
};

int main()
{
    Command<Parameter<int>, Parameter<float>> c;
}
```

Comment: +1!  You could also try `template<class T>struct ExpandArgs:T{};`

Comment: That would also work; but I prefer the current solution as it's a bit less obscure. Anyway, thanks again for your help! I had no idea in how many ways you can express basically the same thing here. In case anyone's interested, here's the link to the Connect bug I filed: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/862959/c-parameter-pack-expansion-fails