# Is an unexpanded parameter pack in a function signature template argument for a class template allowed? (Possible VS2013 bug)

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11

Is an unexpanded parameter pack allowed in a function signature that is a template parameter to another template?

I expect that it is, but I get different result from different compilers. The following minimal example works with Apple LLVM version 6.0 and gcc 4.8.1 but not VS2013.

Example in Ideone: http://ideone.com/xuyhRb

From my searching, this may be a bug in VS2013, possibly related to: [Parameter pack expansion fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347287/parameter-pack-expansion-fails)
However, the solutions given there do not work, the problem seems to be specific to having the unexpanded parameter pack in the function signature. If we replace this in VS2013 with another template to create the function type, it compiles.

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename ...Args>
struct TypeList {};

typedef TypeList<int, float, string> Types;

template <typename ...Args>
struct MakeTupleOfTypes;

template <typename ...Args>
struct MakeTupleOfTypes<TypeList<Args...>>
{
    typedef tuple<Args...> type;
};

template <typename ...Args>
struct MakeTupleOfFunction;

template <typename ...Args>
struct MakeTupleOfFunction<TypeList<Args...>>
{
    typedef tuple<function<void(Args)>...> type; // <-- VS2013 error here
};


typedef TypeList<int, float, string> Types;
typedef MakeTupleOfTypes<Types>::type TupleOfTypes;
typedef MakeTupleOfFunction<Types>::type TupleOfFunctions;

void f1(int x) { cout << x << endl; }
void f2(float x) { cout << x << endl; }
void f3(string x) { cout << x << endl; }

int main()
{
    TupleOfTypes values;
    get<0>(values) = 42;
    get<1>(values) = 3.14159;
    get<2>(values) = "Hello, World!";

    TupleOfFunctions functions;
    get<0>(functions) = &f1;
    get<1>(functions) = &f2;
    get<2>(functions) = &f3;

    get<0>(functions)(get<0>(values));
    get<1>(functions)(get<1>(values));
    get<2>(functions)(get<2>(values));

    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio fails with:

```
error C3520: 'Args': parameter pack must be expanded in this context.
```

at the line

Fix for VS2013: use this template to avoid having an unexpanded parameter pack in the function signature.

```
template <typename Arg>
struct MakeFunction
{
    typedef function<void(Arg)> type;
};
```

and

```
template <typename ...Args>
struct MakeTupleOfFunction<TypeList<Args...>>
{
    typedef tuple<typename MakeFunction<Args>::type...> type;
};
```

Comment: @Yakk, it would be a typo. The code with the fix in VS2013 works for me. You corrected it I guess?

Comment: @Jarod42, Indeed. Fixed. Didn't have a compiler in front of me when I wrote that last comment, and my brain compiler isn't that good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks very much like a VS bug to me, since that's a perfectly valid pattern expansion to use. VS's variadics implementation is extremely flaky, in my experience.

That said, this primary template:

```
template <typename ...Args>
struct MakeTupleOfTypes;
```

should really not be varadic, since the template only accepts one `TypeList`:

```
template <typename ArgsList>
struct MakeTupleOfTypes;
```

Comment: Would you say it is necessarily wrong to have a variadic template for the initial definition? I agree it is unnecessary in this case but would it have any bad consequences (other than adding unnecessary complexity)?

Comment: Yes. If the user accidentally passes too many arguments, he'll get "instantiating undefined template" instead of "too many arguments". So it make the error messages worse.