# List of values (of any types) as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

My class has a static constexpr member function `get` and I need it to return a pointer to the first element (declared `char key;`) of an arbitrary struct generated from template arguments.

This is what I have:

```
template <char id, typename DataType, int... args>
struct MyStruct {
    static constexpr DataType member { id, args... };

    static constexpr void *get() {
        return(&member.key);
    }
};
```

This works as long as all members of DataType (after the first) are of type `int` but what if they're a mix of `int` and `void *`? How should I change the template to allow that?

This is for a foreign function interface between languages, so the other end checks the key, and based on that it knows the type of structure that follows it in memory.

Comment: When you are talking about `void *` parameters, are you talking about the type `void *`, or are you talking about `constexpr void *` values?  If the latter, I am not sure how you intend to create them,

Comment: @md5i the latter. They're for a light pseudo-RTTI system. `template <typename Type> static constexpr void *makeTypeID()` returns the address of `placeholder` in `template <typename Type> struct TypeStore {static constexpr char placeholder = 0;}` and the address works as a unique identifier for that type. The current problem is how to store more data in TypeStore for handling data structures like vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send any values of any types as template parameter. You can't send value of structs or floating point value, or string literals. I propose a solution that I think would replace the need of any of that.

### option 1

Just define a struct with a static function that returns your object.

```
struct Initializer {
    constexpr static SomeType initialize(char id) {
        return SomeType{id, 1.2, "blerg"};
    }
};
```

Then, send the initializer as template parameter:

```
template <char id, typename Init> struct MyStruct {
    using DataType = decltype(Init::initialize(id));

    static constexpr DataType member = Init::initialize(id);     
    static constexpr void *get() {
        return(&member.key);
    }
};
```

### option 2

You can put the initialize function inside the struct intended to be `Datatype`, so you can do this:

```
DataType = DataType::initialize(id);
```

### option 3

In the struct initializer, you can alternatively create a tuple with all the extra arguments your `DataType` struct need. That would be the closest solution from the code you wanted to write. The initialize struct would then look like this:

```
struct Initializer {
    constexpr static std::tuple<float, const char*> args{1.5, "patate"};
    using args_t = decltype(args);
};
```

Then you must unpack it using a integer sequence:

```
template<char, typename, typename, typename> struct Base;

template<char id, typename DataType, typename Init, std::size_t... S>
struct Base<char, DataType, Init, std::index_sequence<S...>> {
    constexpr static DataType member{id, std::get<S>(Init::args)...};
};
```

You can extend `Base` with `MyStruct` now:

```
template <char id, typename DataType, typename Init> 
struct MyStruct : Base<id, DataType, Init,
    std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename Init::args_t>::value>
> {
    static constexpr void *get() {
        return(&member.key);
    }
};
```

These are a bunch of useful solution. I'm sure there are others out there.

Comment: I put each type of parameter in a separate parameter pack and enforced a particular order for them. That works, except Visual Studio is having problems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347287/parameter-pack-expansion-fails so it seems your suggestions might be cleaner and more flexible. I'll try them out.

Comment: On vidual studio it migth be harder. I advise you to upgrade to the last version, anything below 2015 update 1 will have trouble with `constexpr`.

Comment: Note that the third option is using c++14, if you want to make it work with c++11, you must implement your odn version of `std::tuple`, `std::get` and `std::index_sequence`. tuples and get are only marked as constexpr since c++14, and index_sequence was added after c++11.